# Create a new point from Lat and Long in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm working on a multi page app and I'm facing difficulty in retrieving the coordinates entered in one page and using it to display the data in another. I'm geocoding the address entered into the first page and storing it in the Local cache.

On the second page, I'm retrieving these using

```
var srcLat = localStorage.getItem('srcLat');
var srcLong = localStorage.getItem('srcLong');
var destLat = localStorage.getItem('destLat');
var destLong = localStorage.getItem('destLong');
```

I now want to find the distance and the commute time between these 2 coordinates. Is there any way to convert the srcLat and srcLong into a point called src that can represent these coordinates so that I can use this-

```
displayRoute(srcPoint, destPoint, directionsService,
directionsDisplay);
```

If there are any other solutions, please do suggest.

PS: The app is for a project demo and hence will be running on only chrome. Hence the use of local storage.

Comment: What issue are you having doing that?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  ([fiddle1 (setter)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/L1u4z0ak/1/), [fiddle2 (getter)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/z6mbtvh6/))

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you have to create a latLng object, which would look like this

```
var srcPoint = {lat: srcLat, lng: srcLong}
var destPoint = {lat: destLat, lng: destLong}
```

This object then represents a Point on the map.

If your interesting in the Doc´s that explains, what a latLng Object is take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-latlng-literal?hl=de)